# Meaning with/without of between noun and gerund

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Their constructing the monument was something of a feat.
>
> Their constructing of the monument was something of a feat.

As a native speaker , what sort of difference in meaning do you sense between the sentences , bearing in mind that the only difference is the adding of "of" to the second sentence ?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer this question due to the fact that a native speaker would not say *either* of your sentences.

[image]

I suggest using:

"Their construction of the monument was something of a feat."

Answer (score 0):

As an American native English speaker, I perceive no difference in meaning between the two example sentences; however, without additional context justifying its inclusion (for instance, in the preceding paragraph), I would drop "Their" from either sentence; i. e.,

> "Constructing the monument was something of a feat."

The only problem with either sentence is that "something of a feat" is a weak description. Constructing a backyard BBQ is "something of a feat." Constructing a monument is presumably something much more than that; for instance,

> Constructing the monument was a considerable (or enormous, or magnificent) feat.

Answer (score 0):

*Construct* takes an object, and gerunds can take objects.  *The monument* is an object of *constructing*.

> Their constructing the monument was something of a feat

You can use *of X* to explicitly provide the reason, purpose, or "destination" of many nouns.  *The monument* is the "destination" or reason for the constructing.  As gerunds are nouns this can be done with them as well.

> Their constructing of the monument was something of a feat.

Both expressions are basically two paths that arrive at the same meaning.

If you wished to draw attention to the monument - i.e. if the act of constructing the monument is a feat and not just the act of constructing (without regard to what is being constructed) - then the second sentence would be better.